# How to make a prediction request over a text snippet from AutoML Entity Extraction?

Tags: python, google-cloud-automl

I have created annoted dataset in AutoML Entity Extraction. It is successfully deployed. How do I make a request from `Python` using `google-cloud-automl` library to make a prediction request?

Library already have [an example](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/master/automl#example-usage) code but I am confused a little bit about payload structure

```
from google.cloud.automl_v1beta1 import PredictionServiceClient

client = PredictionServiceClient()
model_path = client.model_path('my-project-123', 'us-central', 'model-name')
payload = {...}
params = {'foo': 1}
response = client.predict(model_path, payload, params=params)
```

I looked at, how to create payload and found [this](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/entity-analysis/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.automl.v1beta1#google.cloud.automl.v1beta1.ExamplePayload). I want predictions for a single sentence and gets results for it. For example: 'Tim Cook is the CEO of Apple', I want to send this text for prediction to AutoML Entity Extraction.

So I dug through a bit and found [this](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/entity-analysis/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.automl.v1beta1#google.cloud.automl.v1beta1.TextSnippet).

How should I make request to AutoML entity extraction from python?

How does the `payload` look like? What is the structure of `model_path`?

What is the parameter in third argument for the function `client.predict`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has already posted a sample [python code](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/entity-analysis/docs/predict#automl-nl-example-python) for text snippet in the product page for analyzing entities.

```
# TODO(developer): Uncomment and set the following variables
# project_id = '[PROJECT_ID]'
# compute_region = '[COMPUTE_REGION]'
# model_id = '[MODEL_ID]'
# file_path = '/local/path/to/file'

from google.cloud import automl_v1beta1 as automl

automl_client = automl.AutoMlClient()

# Create client for prediction service.
prediction_client = automl.PredictionServiceClient()

# Get the full path of the model.
model_full_id = automl_client.model_path(
    project_id, compute_region, model_id
)

# Read the file content for prediction.
with open(file_path, "rb") as content_file:
    snippet = content_file.read()

# Set the payload by giving the content and type of the file.
payload = {"text_snippet": {"content": snippet, "mime_type": "text/plain"}}

# params is additional domain-specific parameters.
# currently there is no additional parameters supported.
params = {}
response = prediction_client.predict(model_full_id, payload, params)
print("Prediction results:")
for result in response.payload:
    print("Predicted entity label: {}".format(result.display_name))
    print("Predicted confidence score: {}".format(result.text_extraction.score))
    print("Predicted text segment: {}".format(result.text_extraction.text_segment.content))
    print("Predicted text segment start offset: {}".format(result.text_extraction.text_segment.start_offset))
    print("Predicted text segment end offset : {}".format(result.text_extraction.text_segment.end_offset))
    print("\n")
```